# Selecting columns that have column names within a list in R

Tags: r

I have a list of words, generated as follows:

```
exString = "hello words are cool words are neat"
wordList = unique(unlist(str_split(exString, ' ')))

wordList
"hello" "words" "are"   "cool"  "neat"
```

I want to use the list of words to select the columns of a data frame that are the same words.

```
hello <- c(1,2,3)
words <- c(4,5,6)
cactus <- c(7,8,9)
exDataframe <- data.frame(hello, words, cactus)

hello     words    cactus
 1          4       7
 2          5       8
 3          6       9
```

So since "hello" and "words" are in `wordList` those columns would be selected and the resulting dataframe would be:

```
hello     words    
 1          4     
 2          5      
 3          6
```

Comment: `wordList` is not a `list`, but a `vector`.  When you `unlist`, the `list` it is converted to a `vector`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `intersect` with `names` of the data and the 'wordList'

```
exDataframe[intersect(wordList, names(exDataframe))]
   hello words
1     1     4
2     2     5
3     3     6
```

Or may use `%in%`

```
exDataframe[names(exDataframe) %in% wordList]
```

---

or with `select` and `any_of`

```
library(dplyr)
exDataframe %>%
     select(any_of(wordList))
```

-output

```
  hello words
1     1     4
2     2     5
3     3     6
```

---

Or using `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
gvr(exDataframe, vars = wordList)
  hello words
1     1     4
2     2     5
3     3     6
```